# Boot loading surgery

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, grub, windows-server-2008

Ok I think I think I've much work to do, I want to dual boot windows server and xp, but I've linux and grub installed. But before I begin I need to ask some questions.

The current situation:

```
           Linux
```

boot -  grub <

```
          Windows server 2008
```

My linux distro is on an external hard drive, and windows is on my main hard drive.
I ultimately want to remove grub and linux from my system and replace linux with windows xp.
The problem is I don't have the repair disk for windows server, and thus I cannot repair the bootloader. I cannot replace linux with xp before grub has been removed because if I do grub will complain about not being able to find the operating systems, and will make me unable to boot to windows.

So question 1: How to repair my bootloader so I can dual boot windows server and windows xp? or how to replace linux with windows xp in my grub menu.

2nd:

Like I said I've windows server 2008 on my main hard drive. I'm not sure but I thought that windows xp didn't feature partition selection? I thought win xp was a blind missile that just installed itself wherever it could. Am I right?

So my questions are:

1. How to repair my bootloader so I can dual boot windows server and windows xp? or how to replace linux with windows xp in my grub menu.
2. Does anyone know if windows xp (home edition) features partition selection? And if it doesn't how to get it on my external hard drive without overwriting my main hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

According to one user here: http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/download-windows-vista-x64-recovery-disc/
A vista recovery disk can properly repair bootloader on 2008.  The repair disk is available for download on the linked to page.

As far as getting XP to install, I would hide the 2008 partition with whatever disk mgmt utility and just install.  Then put the necessary lines in the boot.ini file on the 2k8 server

Comment: Ok I'll see if that works

Comment: any news? if it fails how so...i'll sort it out